# How to add custom preprocessor/postprocessor to django-wiki render?

Tags: python, django, django-wiki

I am planning to add my custom "syntax extension" to my wiki based on django-wiki (https://github.com/django-wiki/django-wiki).

For example I want something like this:

```
{mytemplate param1="value"}
```

to unfold to something like that:

```
 <div class="mytemplate"><some_code_that_uses_param1></div>
```

So, how to add such custom syntax extension to django-wiki?
(I'd prefer to do it without modifying django-wiki's source code)

Answer (score 0):

OK, after some digging, I found a solution. Maybe it could be useful for someone.

Django-wiki uses python markdown module (https://github.com/Python-Markdown/markdown). It has a couple of broken (outdated) examples inside its documentation on github (hope they will be updated someday), but still they could start working after few fixes. Here is working (with current version of python-markdown) example of markdown extension:

```
from markdown.inlinepatterns import Pattern
from markdown.util import etree
from markdown.extensions import Extension
MYPATTERN = r'\{mytemplate (?P<param>\w+)\}'
class EmphasisPattern(Pattern):
    def handleMatch(self, m):
        el = etree.Element('em')
        el.text = m.group('param')
        return el
class MyExtension(Extension):
    def extendMarkdown(self, md, md_globals):
        em = EmphasisPattern(MYPATTERN)
        md.inlinePatterns.add('example', em, "<not_strong")
def makeExtension(configs={}):
    return MyExtension(configs=configs)
```

To make it work with django-wiki you should add WIKI_MARKDOWN_KWARGS to django's settings.py:

```
WIKI_MARKDOWN_KWARGS = {
    'extensions': [
        'my_extenstion_filename_inside_django_project_folder',
    ]
}
```